# What makes us believe that the set $(T,V,N)$ completely describe a closed system interacting with a heat bath?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

In statistical mechanics, a canonical ensemble is described by fixed $(T,V,N)$ out of which one is intensive and two are extensive. How can I be sure that this set is sufficient to completely describe the system? What about the pressure of the system? Why not consider the set $(P,V,N)$ instead or all of them $(T,P,V,N)$? Is there an implicit assumption here?

Answer (score 1):

Because 3 are enough.

Both $(T,V,N)$ and $(T,V,P)$ are equally valid and enough to describe the full system. In fact, I am myself more used to the latter version with pressure (that is an easier parameter to measure engineering-wise). Giving $(T,V,P,N)$ will "over-describe" the system - meaning, redundancy and unnecessity. No problem with that - it's just not necessary.

It all comes down to the ideal-gas-law:

$$PV=NRT$$

It contains free 4 variables, and only 3 are needed. It could be any 3. All 4 would be unnecessary, as the fourth can always be found with the other 3.

Note that this talk concerns ideal gasses. For non-ideal (real) gasses and fluids, there can be more or fewer parameters involved than in the ideal-gas-law.

Comment: Since the original question doesn’t specifically mention an ideal gas, I think this answer could be strengthened by discussing why the number is generally three (rather than two or four, for example). This can be traced back to the implicit assumptions when we set up the system: that we’re going to consider (1) heat, (2) one type of work (i.e., $P\,dV$ work), and (3) one flavor of matter.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Thank you for the comment. I agree but assumed the question to regard ideal gasses, since $(P,T,V,N)$ was described as "all of them".

Comment: I don't think that $(T,V,N)$ and $(T,V,P)$ are equally valid parameter sets to describe a system. While it is true that for an ideal gas one can specify $T$, $V$ and $P$ and from there compute $N$, this is not generally the case for real systems -- there might be multiple or no solution for $N$. I think a description in independent variables like $N$,$V$, $T$ is inherently better than one that uses conjugate variables such as $P$ and $V$.

Comment: @user8153 They may be fundamentally better and more reliable. But they are not easier to measure. Pressure and volume are practical parameters. They are valid for use for ideal gases as discussed. Which is why it is important to identify if a gas is ideal or close to ideal.

Comment: @Steeven I agree on the measurement part, but (part of) the question was specifically why we use $T,V,N$ rather than $P,V,N$ to describe an ensemble in statistical mechanics. To say that specifying any three of the four variables $T,V,P,N$ is equally valid is misleading imho: $T$, $V$, and $N$ are independent variables and you can specify them separately, while it's in general not clear whether that's possible with $P$, $V$, $N$.

Comment: @user8153 I understand your point. I do hope my comment in the answer - and this comment thread - will make that clear for the OP.